# Multiprocessing in Python on Windows

Tags: python, windows

I am trying out the examples listed in the python docs http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html
particularly these two on Windows:

1)

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print 'hello', name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

2)

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os

def info(title):
    print title
    print 'module name:', __name__
    print 'parent process:', os.getppid()
    print 'process id:', os.getpid()

def f(name):
    info('function f')
    print 'hello', name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    info('main line')
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Here is the problem: I don't get any output from the child process. It works on Linux though. What is going on?

Comment: I suggest you do exception handling. That will give us more clarity !

Comment: I don't get any exceptions except for the os.getppid in parent process. If I remove that I just get the parent's output and the child prints nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

example 1 works well.( I hope you saved the program in a file and then executed it else it will not recognise the function f at all).

example 2 won't work if u want the parent process's id. There is no getppid in windows.

Just take the print os.getppid and execute, its brilliant as ever !

Please refer this for more by [Doug](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/multiprocessing/basics.html). (**UPDATE**: The original link isn't working, [here](http://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html) is something similar.)

Comment: I saved it in a file. Which version of Python do you have?

Comment: 2.6.5. But that doesn't matter anyways unless if yours is not in 2.6 or higher. Because its a newer addition to 2.6

Comment: Lucky , we have Doug on it for you ! http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/multiprocessing/basics.html